# Unfortunately the app has stopped working - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This happens on button click

My Activity.XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText android:id="@+id/enter_number"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enter_number"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_calculate" 
    android:onClick="calculate"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

.java file

```
    package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tables extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the message from the intent
        int number=0;
        int i=1;
        int next=0;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        number=Integer.parseInt(message);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        String[] myString = new String[10]; //create array
        for (i = 1; i <= myString.length; i++) { 
             next= number + next;
             myString[i] =  String.valueOf(number)+'x'+String.valueOf(i)+'='+String.valueOf(next)+'\n';
            // textView.setText(myString[i]);  
            // setContentView(textView);
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : myString){
          builder.append(s+" ");
        textView.setText(builder.toString());
        }
        setContentView(textView);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tables, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think the error is during displaying. But can't find the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Firstly, any force-close should be accompanied by a LogCat log (the red text you get when it happens). Second, you put the `onClick` method as `calculate`. I don't see a `calculate` method here...

Comment: Please post the logcat. It is probably a problem  in how you set the textview as the content view

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `calculate` method  in your activty. As you have set the `onClick` property in the layout file, when you click the button, the Android Framework will try to call the follow method of Tables activity :

```
  public void calculate(View v){
      //put you code here this will be execute when the button is clicked
  }
```

Comment: I fixed you answer ( the signature for the expected method was incorrect), but I haven't not read the code when I did that. As @mr.j05hua notice, the layout file is not used. So the problem is other thing. A textview is set as the content view, bu I do see a layout param being set. This is very likelu to cause a problem, but need logcat to confirm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the layout file is for your main activity, not for the `Tables` activity. Make sure that your `MainActivity` class has a method with the signature `public void calculate(View view)` so the activity can respond to the button click. It's likely that this is the problem, rather than a problem with displaying the `Tables` activity.